# Why are MOSFETs called voltage controlled devices even though we have to push in charge/current to charge the input capacitances?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, capacitance, voltage-controlled-amplifier

I was wondering why MOSFETs are called voltage controlled devices when the input capacitances of the MOSFET (Cgd and Cgs) need to be charged in order to turn ON. Wouldn't that mean that they are current/charge controlled devices?

Comment: Can you see the gate current in the drain current equation?

Comment: No I cannot, but I always thought of that explanation as a mathematical explanation. But the fact that the drain current equation has Vgs and that is only applicable when we push enough charge in, is what I was wondering about.

Comment: The current is only needed to turn the MOSFET on or to turn it off (for a very short period).  But after this period no current is needed to sustain the MOSFET turn-on state. On the other hand, the BJTs need continuous base current to flow to keep the BJT turn-on.

Comment: @G36 Thank You! Makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage between gate and source is what is controlling the conductivity of the channel. It is the electrical field, not a current that has influence.
Yes, every FET has some specific gate capacitance, so you can calculate or measure the amount of charge needed to reach a specific control voltage. But in the end it is still the voltage that effects the channel.

Comment: To add to that, it is an external voltage stimulus that controls the device - not a current.

Answer (score 0):

You can model it that way if you like. But maybe it's a little easier to start designing a gate driver from the gate voltage requirement, and derive the gate current/charge requirement from that.